# Не работают настройки cookies для сессии в express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Дорого времени суток,

Не могу понять, почему не работают настройки maxAge из конфигуратора:

```js
app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'sessiondata',
  keys: ['key1', 'key2'],
  cookie: { //secure: true,
            //httpOnly: true,
            //domain: 'example.com',
            //path: 'foo/bar',
            maxAge: 1
          }
    })
);
```

При это указание maxAge вручную работает:

```js
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
res.cookie('id', 'lol'); //не работает
res.cookie('id2', '2222222', { maxAge: 1222});//работает
res.send(req.cookies.id+req.cookies.id2);
  //res.render('login');
});
```

Comment: Потому что ожидается, что параметр maxAge — это число, а Вы присваиваете ему строку? (`maxAge: a number representing the milliseconds from Date.now() for expiry`)

Comment: Я и так и так пробовал :( И без кавычек и с.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This module has no relation to the res.cookie command, so the settings from this module have no effect on res.cookie.

> этот модуль не имеет отношения к команде res.cookie, поэтому устнановки из этого модуля не имеют отношение к этой команде.